# How to do order by child inside another child Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get all data ordered asc and desc by child value that inside another child. In main scope of class:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference("university");
```

i have data structure like this

```
{
"university": {
    "13": {
      "name": "value"
      "exam": {
        "exam_date": "value"
        "reg_date": "value"
      }
    }
    "15": {
      "name": "value"
      "exam": {
        "exam_date": "value"
        "reg_date": "value"
      }
    }
    "20": {
      "name": "value"
      "exam": {
        "exam_date": "value"
        "reg_date": "value"
      }
    }
}
```

}

First I try this way `Query q=dbRef.orderByChild("13/exam/exam_date")`
but it is getting data like when i use ValueEventListener with dbRef directly without ordering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
Query q=dbRef.orderByChild("13/exam/exam_date")
```

with

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("university").orderByChild("exam/exam_date");
```

Comment: thank you it is work fine i just change Query q=dbRef.orderByChild("13/exam/exam_date") to Query q=dbRef.orderByChild("exam/exam_date");

Answer (score 0):

```
 firebaseDatabaseRef.child(AppConstants.RootNode.userRoomGroupIds).child(myUserId).orderByChild(AppConstants.FireBaseRoom.LAST_MESSAGE+"/"+AppConstants.LASTMESSAGE.MESSAGE_TIME_STAMP).startAt(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This query give data from next to my current milisec so i use orderByChild in which give refrence to particular child /lastmessage/timeStamp

Answer (score 0):

Now, I use orderBy(FieldPath) to do this

```
Query q=dbRef.orderBy(FieldPath.of("13", "exam", "exam_date"))
```